# Does Docker have a GUI on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I already had docker installed on my ubuntu, and used it through terminal, and recently saw it had a GUI on Windows and Mac OS. Does it have a GUI on Linux now? If I uninstall docker and docker compose and go through a new installation process will it have a GUI? I just need to know it before wasting my time doing that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a google machine. I did a quick search and found https://github.com/docker/kitematic which has a ubuntu build if you look into releases

Answer (score 2):

check this [portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) ,

it's running inside container, it can manage docker container by mounting `/var/run/docker.sock

no need to uninstall docker and docker compose to use portainer , it's working with the current installation